# Test stripe 3ds payments with integration tests

Tags: stripe-payments, integration-testing, 3d-secure, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-sca

I have an issue with writing end to end api integration test for flow where I need to confirm 3ds payment. The flow is:

- pay for the item
- confirm 3ds payment (all payments require 3ds)
- check if order is in correct state

Now this is an issue as I make a call to pay then stripe requires 3DS and my payment gets stuck on awaiting user confirmation. Is there a way how I could confirm this payment in my test so I could see if the order went to correct state after 3DS challenge has been completed?

I tried to ser a return url on payment intent confirmation but when calling the URL stripe returns I do not get same HTML back as it is rendered in browser, from this reason I can not use this to extract what I need to do to confirm the payment. This used to work until recently but now stripe has made some changes to their 3DS confirm website and it is not possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to programmatically handle 3DS. The recommendation is to mock the response here to a successful 3DS confirmation as opposed to actually completing 3DS in the flow.